# Can I create a struct out of a TypeInfo_Struct?

Tags: types, d

I have a TypeInfo_Stuct; how do I create a struct out of this?

```
struct A {
    int example;
}

TypeInfo test = typeid(A);

void main() {
    // how do I create a structure of type A from test in here? 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. It implies polymorphic construction which is not provided for structs in D.

Such functionality is supported by druntime for classes though:

```
class A {}

auto ti = typeid(A);

void main()
{
    auto instance = cast(A) ti.create();
    assert(instance);
}
```

One can possibly implement similar factory infrastructure for types other than classes but that is not available out of the box (and is somewhat discouraged).

Comment: I guess I'll use classes than! Thanks!

Comment: A possible option would be to create a memory block with length == ti.init.length, then copy ti.init over to it, and cast to the struct... though then again, if you know the struct type to cast to, you can just do `new Struct()` instead... so you could make one with typeinfo but not really use it.

Comment: Situation is actually similar for classes are `create` returns `Object`, not specific type and cast is needed. Though it is mitigated by the being able to cast to common interface instead and use virtual dispatch instead. This is pretty much the reason why it is not really useful for structs.